# After Effects animation - text rotating with CC Cylinder

Tags: animation, adobe-after-effects

I'm new to this site and to After Effects. Could somebody point me to a tutorial, to show me how to create the rotating text below (just nabbed this gif from a previous question that somebody posted)

Any help would be much appreciated!

[image]

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nfSltOnO-xg

Comment: Have you actually tried to replicate it? It's pretty much as simply as applying the CC Cylinder effect

Comment: Than you John and Cai for your help! Its just I'm a complete novice to After Effects! much appreciated!